# How to enable back arrow keys

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I disabled arrow keys with

```
noremap <Up> <Nop>
noremap <Down> <Nop>
noremap <Left> <Nop>
noremap <Right> <Nop>
```

I now want arrow keys back. I removed this from my .vimrc and the configuration still applies.

What is the default configuration for arrow keys that I should add to my .vimrc to make them work again?

Comment: You don't need any configuration they work by default. If you quit vim `:qa!` and restart it, it should work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing's first: did you restart Vim after altering your `.vimrc`? Unless you `:source` it manually or have autocommands set up to automate this when it is changed, it is only read on start-up.

If you remove the configuration from your `.vimrc` then it should no longer apply. Most likely some other part of your configuration is affecting these keys.

Try running the following command within Vim to see if your arrow keys are currently mapped, and if so, what mapped them:

```
:verbose nmap <Up>
```

If that reports `No mapping found`, then something else is going wrong. It's worth checking that Vim is actually receiving the arrow-key events. Try entering insert mode and then pressing the series of keystrokes:

<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>

That should tell you the keycode that Vim is receiving when you press an arrow key, and you can then investigate further why that is not resulting in movement for you.

Comment: I'm a dumbass and forgot to remove mapping from .vimrc. I didn't know about :verbose and it helped me find this. Thank you.

Comment: @bemug Haha easily done! Glad you've solved your issue :).